# Is it possible to deep link to Buddypress pages via login?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have a WordPress installation on which I'm using the BuddyPress plugin. I am also using a plugin to send daily digest e-mails to my users to offer them links to forums which have had new posts.

The problem is that if a user follows one of these links when they're not logged in, they're just taken to a 404 'Page Not Found' page.

Is there any way to redirect them to a login page which redirects them to the desired location after logging in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just take control of your 404.php page from theme's file. Implement this in your theme's `404.php` page to redirect some specific users to another page:

```
if( HTTP-REFERER == 'YOU-KNOW-HOW-TO-DETECT-BUDDYPRESS-USERS' )
$redirect_to= 'http://example.com/';    
//redirect_to is the main part here. For details on this parameter, see here: http:

wp_redirect($redirect_to); 
EXIT();


/* REST OF THE FILE FROM 404.PHP, they remain unchanged */
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect